# How do I say 'I end up' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say 'I end up' in Spanish? I'd like to say it in this context :

> I wanted to get a cheaper hotel, but I ended up getting an expensive
>   one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can say: "Quería encontrar un hotel barato, pero al final terminé en uno caro".

Answer (score 6):

You can say:

> Estaba buscando un hotel barato y (terminé/acabé) en uno más caro

or

> Quería un hotel barato y (terminé/acabé) en uno más caro

Comment: Be careful with *acabar*, which has a sexual meaning in some places.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon esa no la sabia, porfa me podrias decir en que lugares, como cultura general, si sabia del significado de coger en mexico, argentica pero no de acabar

Comment: En Argentina, por lo menos, *acabar* es tener un orgasmo.

Comment: En Colombia también, pero si se le añade la acción (u otra palabra) a la oración, se le quita el _doble sentido_:
Ej: Estaba buscando un hotel barato y acabé _pagando la estancia/residencia_ en uno más caro...

Answer (score 2):

This will be the most accurate one for your sentence, I think:

> Quería (coger) un hotel barato, pero acabé cogiendo uno mas caro.

The sentence "ended up" can be traslated like `acabé` or `terminé`.

The verb "To get", for an hotel, can be traslated into `coger`, `hacer noche`, `encontrar`, etc.

As in Latin American Spanish speaking countries the verb `coger` has a totally different meaning, the traslation should obviously use a different one for this countries.

Comment: "coger" is mostly used in Spain, but understandable in all Hispanoamerica.

Comment: I think "coger" would not be the first option for a native speaker from Spain in this case.

Comment: @joragupra As a native spanish speaker I can asure you that is perfectly normal to use `coger` in this context. Another option will be `pillar`, but only in a very informal situations.

Comment: @SysDragon No, it isn't, there are much better words for that, not to mention the meaning ```coger``` has for Latin American speakers. And ```pillar``` is just a horrible slang expresion.

Comment: @joragupra Hmm... yes, it is. I'm talking spanish for 26 years. I readed hundreds of books. `coger` is not only perfectly valid, but very common to use in this context. And yes, `pillar` is a slang expression, and `coger` in Latin American speakers has a different meaning, so there obviously won't be valid.

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks for the information about your experience speaking Spanish but I think that does not bring anything to the table. Of course, you can use generic verbs like ```coger``` or ```hacer``` for almost everything but that wouldn't show an extensive vocabulary, don't you think?

Comment: @joragupra As I said, it's perfectly valid and the most common one in this context in Spain. And if you read my answer you can see that I propose some alternatives. I think you're taking things out of proportion.

Comment: @SysDragon I apologize as I did not intend to sound rude, it was just my personal opinion. But of course your answer is totally OK.

Comment: @joragupra Thanks for the explanation. Edited for clarification with the Latin American meaning of the verb.

Comment: @joragupra "coger" would definitely be the first and most natural choice for a native speaker in this context, at least in Spain.

Comment: En cuba tambien seria una de las opciones preferidas, lo que ya estoy curado de decir coger por el significado sexual que tiene en casi toda latinoamerica